# Ubuntu 14.04 login screen ui issue

Tags: unity, login, 14.04

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. I failed to upgrade first time and then I logged into terminal using ctrl+alt+f1 and used the following command to upgrade

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And I was able to upgrade to 14.04 LTS but I am experiencing some issues with my login scren ui. Not sure how to fix.

Tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` but no luck :(

Attached is the screen shot of the same.[image]

**Added:**

contents of `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6            File: 50-ubuntu.conf                                

[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
```

Comment: You must probably post your /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf in your description ...

Comment: @Venki just updated the question with the contents on 50-ubuntu.conf as requested.

Comment: Hmm.. Seems fine. I am not an expert I must confess. But I have heard that editing the ownership of Xauthority might help ... But I am not sure. Search around Ask Ubuntu about login screen errors in general and most of them suggest that....

Comment: I even tried re-installing unity but NO LUCK! :(

Comment: Then try removing xauthority ... I dunno if it works. But worth a try. If it didnt work I am sorry! I can't help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Opened Ubuntu Tweak, went to Tweaks > Login Settings. Changed Gtk theme to Ambiance. It was set to a different theme. Don't know how or why. And I even checked all the config files in /etc/lightdm beforehand. All of them showed they were using the Ambience GTK theme. So, I don't know what config file Ubuntu Tweak is changing, but changing the theme there fixed the login screen issue for me. Good luck!